# How to get only the process ID for a specified process name on Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, redhat

How to get only the process ID for a specified process name on Linux?

```
ps -ef|grep java
test 31372 31265  0 13:41 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
```

Based on the process id I will write some logic. So how do I get only the process id for a specific process name.

Sample program:

```
PIDS= ps -ef|grep java
if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
echo "nothing"
else
mail test@domain.example
fi
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use:

```
ps -ef | grep '[j]ava'
```

Or if `pgrep` is available then better to use:

```
pgrep -f java
```

Comment: Great answer pgrep -f java . It can be used to get PID only.

Comment: Your first answer doesn't return only the pid, it returns all informations (on Ubuntu). BTW: Could you explain, what the brackets do?  II couldn't find a doc for it.

Comment: Square brackets are used to exclude grep process from ps output

Answer (score 107):

You can pipe your output to awk to print just the PID. For example:

> ```
> ps -ef | grep nginx | awk '{print $2}'
> 9439
> ```

Comment: Works well, hoverver if you use the output as a variable, a | tr -d '\n' must be added at the end of the command.

Comment: It is a program that can be used to select particular records in a file and perform operations upon them. It is so extensive that you can even write some programs with it. [AWK Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Answer (score 80):

Use this: `ps -C <name> -o pid=`

Comment: Why is this voted down? Not only does it seem to work, but does so using the desired command ps, and no pipe filters.

 In my case, I couldn't use pipes (reasons..) so this was a lifesaver. You could spend a whole day reading the man page for PS... thanks @ventsyv

Comment: Maybe because it's not extremely portable, but then again the other solutions aren't either, and the original question was tagged with Redhat Linux. Just happened to see a commit by one of my engineers who needed to have a portable way to detect a specific java process on OSX, RHEL Linux and AIX, and this is what they came up with: `ps -A -o pid,args | grep \[j]ava`.

Answer (score 25):

This command ignore grep process, and just return PID:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Shorter: ps -ef |  grep '[j]ava' | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: I use this to get the PID. Be careful when using the output as a variable, a `| tr -d '\n'` must be added at the end.

Comment: On busybox v1.24.1 , this worked for me:  ps | grep -v grep | grep cli | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: And this:  ps | awk '$NF ~ /cli/ {print $1}'

Comment: Thanks for this comment, the ignore grep processes was a nice addition.

Answer (score 22):

why not just pidof ?

```
pidof <process_name>
```

it will return a list of pids matching the process name

https://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof

Comment: Clean and quick on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: works as long you don't have multiple instance (e.g. java)